# Facebook Open Graph: URL to use for sharing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a customised Facebook share button. The idea is upon clicking on the Facebook share button, it will pick up the meta tags on the page and prefill the share information with a title, description and image that have been curated.

What URL should I be using for the button?
There is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share
and https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php

I heard the latter has been deprecated? And you can append a whole bunch of information to the URL as well?

I can't quite figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

`sharer.php` is not deprecated. It was, for some months, but you can definitely use it. The benefit of using `sharer.php` is that you don´t need to create an App. It´s the easiest way to implement sharing.

Keep in mind that `sharer.php` ONLY takes the URL as parameter, everything else will get loaded from the Open Graph tags.

For example:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F